# Java .getNetworkInterfaces() cannot detect wlan0 on Kali Linux

Tags: java

I was trying to build a gui for airmon-ng and I face a problem with the code .getNetworkInterface. It can detect the wlan0 interface in windows but not as soon as I ran this code in linux. My Kali Linux can detect wlan0 with Iwconfig/Ifconfig, but not with this code.

ifconfig result:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 24189  bytes 1451329 (1.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 24189  bytes 1451329 (1.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f8:1a:67:0e:4a:55  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My Java code

```
nicsa.setText("Please select a wireless interface...");
        int k=99;
        String[]niclist=new String[k];
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> eni = null;
        try {
            eni = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        int i=0;
        for (NetworkInterface ni : Collections.list(eni)) {
            niclist[i]=ni.getName();
            if(niclist[i].matches("^[w,l,a,n]{4}\\d{1}")||niclist[i].matches("^[w,l,a,n]{4}\\d{2}")){
                nic.addItem(niclist[i]);
                i++;
            }else{nicsa.setText("No Wireless Interface found..");
            }
        }
        Process p = null;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ifconfig");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        try {
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
  BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          p.getInputStream()));
  String line = "";
  String output = "";

        try {
            while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                output += line + "\n";
            }     } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
nicinfo.setText(output);
```

Comment: Why even use a regular expression at all?  Why not just `if (niclist[i].startsWith("wlan"))`?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i think i will change it to this, completely good idea. Any Idea on my problem?

Comment: Is the `wlan0` interface actually up?  I believe NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() will not include any interfaces which are down.

Comment: Yes, the wlan0 interface is up.

Comment: @VGR Finally it works when i first connect wlan0 to a specific wifi network then use that .getnetworkintefrece to scan the avaliable interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex looks a little funny:

```
if(niclist[i].matches("^[w,l,a,n]{4}\\d{1}")||niclist[i].matches("^[w,l,a,n]{4}\\d{2}"))
```

I would go with the following

```
if(niclist[i].matches("^wlan\\d{1,2}"))
```

This way you know you're looking for a string that starts with wlan and ends with one to two digits.

Have you tried dumping out a debug statement on the strings being returned?

Can you run this program in a debugger and step through the logic?

---

```
    for (NetworkInterface ni : Collections.list(eni)) {
        niclist[i]=ni.getName();
        if(niclist[i].matches("^wlan\\d{1,2}")){
            // Try dumping here
            System.out.println("NIC Name: "+niclist[i]);
            nic.addItem(niclist[i]);
            i++;
        }else{nicsa.setText("No Wireless Interface found..");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Meanwhile, not sure about the debug thing, when i run that on netbean on windows, it detect most of the interface like wlan0 1 2 3 4 5, but not on linux. I have tried to google up and use below code, the result is still same.

String[]niclist=new String[k];
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> eni;
    eni = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    int i=0;
    for (NetworkInterface ni : Collections.list(eni)) {
      niclist[i]=ni.getName();
      i++;
    }
    for(int p=0;p<i;p++){
    System.out.println(niclist[p]);}

Comment: I tried the code in a new project called listnet and run it in linux it turns out to be the same...

Comment: Terminal Result
'root@kali:~/Desktop# java -jar ListNet.jar
root@kali:~/Desktop# '

     
String[]niclist=new String[k];
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> eni;
    eni = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    int i=0;
    for (NetworkInterface ni : Collections.list(eni)) {
        niclist[i]=ni.getName();
        if(niclist[i].matches("^wlan\\d{1,2}")){
            // Try dumping here
            System.out.println("NIC Name: "+niclist[i]);

            i++;

        }

Comment: I'm missing something here - are you seeing a list of wlan interfaces showing in the console or not? Secondly, on the linux system, are you running the development environment there or just pushing the Jar file up there? If you are having difficulty in the program, I would almost suggest uploading groovy to your target system and writing the piece are having difficulty with in groovy. That way you can test it as a script instead of having to build the jar on every modification. Or run with remote debugging.

Comment: Other option is to move the System.out.println just before the if/matches condition - that way you dump /all/ of the attempts

Comment: forgotten to mention, i can see 14 wlan interface on my netbean in windows, and yes i just push the .jar file up and run it through the terminal.
I will try out groovy next morning. One thing i dont understand, why in windows build of that .jar i can get 14 wlan interface but while in linux i cant, it doesnt make sense. Also, that interface i trying to detect is a TPLINK TLWN722N. It can be detected in windows but not in linux.

Comment: There may be a naming discrepancy of some kind - I would run just a stand alone program to see what that call is returning.

Comment: I moved the Print statement before the matches wlan statement, it would display eth0 and localhost, but still not wlan0 that i trying to find... but it would dump out everything in my lappy on windows netbean.

Comment: I think so as well, but if so then we would have to figure out the discrepancy of naming which i totally had no idea. Anyidea on how does linux name their network interfaces? or anyidea on alternative to .getNetworkInterface?

Comment: Finally it works when i first connect wlan0 to a specific wifi network then use that .getnetworkintefrece to scan the avaliable interface. It is just weird...

Comment: Glad some of it worked then - on Windows it enumerates a LARGE number of interfaces I don't have - I had to filter that down using the 'isUp' (I think) to determine which ones were active. Possibly, under Kali, the runtime filters out 'down' or non-connected interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me this, i think thats the issue, where it filter out "isdown" thing.